# strokeStyle() not changing color for fillRect()

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

So I have a canvas. And I want to draw multiple filled rectangles of different colors.

The actual code is very lengthy and has layers of dependencies. Here is the relevant part:

```
var c=document.getElementById("result"); //result is a canvas object
var cnv=c.getContext("2d");
cnv.beginPath();
cnv.strokeStyle="#00F000"; //coloring it green
cnv.moveTo(x,y);  //moving to a specific point on the canvas
cnv.fillRect(x,y,3,33);  //drawing a filled rectangle
cnv.stroke();
cnv.closePath();
```

If I alert(cnv.strokeStyle); it does show that the color has been set to 00F000 and it is drawing the rectangles too. The only problem is that all the drawings are in default (black) color.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fillStyle` instead.

```
var c=document.getElementById("result"); //result is a canvas object
var cnv=c.getContext("2d");
cnv.beginPath();
cnv.fillStyle="#00F000"; //coloring it green
cnv.moveTo(x,y);  //moving to a specific point on the canvas
cnv.fillRect(x,y,3,33);  //drawing a filled rectangle
cnv.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

The **CanvasRenderingContext2D** `fillRect()` method fills an area by a color defined using the `fillStyle` method.

The `stroke()` method however fills the outlines of a path defined by prior calls to `moveTo()`, `lineTo()`, `curveTo()`... with a color set by the `strokeStyle()` method.

In your code snippet there's not an actual path defined so the final call to `stroke()` results in nothing and the only visual output you get is the call to `fillRect()` with it's default black color.

If you want the outlines of the rectangles visible too, you have to call strokeRect() with the same parameters as fillRect().

Here's an example:

```js
var c=document.getElementById("result"); //result is a canvas object
var cnv=c.getContext("2d");
let x=20;
let y=20;
cnv.beginPath();
cnv.strokeStyle="#00F000"; //coloring it green
cnv.moveTo(x,y);  //moving to a specific point on the canvas
cnv.fillRect(x,y,3,33);  //drawing a filled rectangle
cnv.strokeRect(x,y,3,33);
cnv.closePath();
```

```html
<canvas id="result"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the additional detail. Upvoted. I'm marking bluejambo's answer as the solution just as a display of encouragement, since they are a new member. On merit, your answer and explanation is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a stroked rectangle vice a filled one then you have to use `strokeRect()` instead of `fillRect()`. Also both of those allow you to not have to call `fill()` or `stroke()` after because they already do that.

If you were to use `cnv.rect()` then you would need to call stroke or fill after. Be sure not to mix up using `strokeRect()` and `fillRect()` when writing your code.

Also you don’t need to use `moveTo()` with these methods. They are already have x and y belie inputs that are required. Lastly `beginPath()` and `closePath()` are not required for a rectangle since that already incorporate that.

```js
var c=document.getElementById("result");
var cnv=c.getContext("2d");
cnv.strokeStyle="#00F000"; //coloring it green
cnv.strokeRect(20,20,30,33);  //drawing a filled rectangle
```

```html
<canvas id='result'></canvas>
```

You can also do both like this

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

ctx.strokeStyle = "purple"
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgreen"
ctx.rect(20, 20, 50, 50)
ctx.fill()
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Upvoted. Marking the answer by a newbie just as a token of appreciation.